# Whited00r 7.1 on iPod 2G MB model iTunes error 6 when restoring

Tags: ios, itunes, ipod-touch, jailbreak, ipod

So I am trying to get Whited00r 7.1 on my iPod Touch 2G MB using iTunes on MacOS Mojave.I used the installation guide and used the included iREB for Mac to put it in pwned DFU mode.So I put it in pwned DFU mode,open iTunes and option-click the "Restore" button,selected the custom Whited00r ipsw for my ipod touch 2G MB,then it says "Preparing iPod for restore" for mabye 2 seconds,and the the screen on my iPod goes white and it says"An unknown error occured (6)".I am currently using iTunes 12.9.5.Also,when I tried to do the same with recovery mode being stuck at "Preparing iPod for restore" forever and then finally after about 3 minutes it gives me error 1604.I am using the usb port on my computer,not on the keyboard or hub.Any help(Yeah,I know you stack exchange guys take FOREVER to answer)?